# when trying to put images inside the node, they do not remain in the correct position within the force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make my nodes are images, and that these are located in the node. but for some reason they are staying in the upper left corner. I have tried many things based on examples but I do not know where my problem lies.

[image]

```
var node = g.selectAll("g.node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  //.filter(function(d){ return d.type=="circle"; })
var NodeCircleEnter= node.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class","node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })

  NodeCircleEnter
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return colorNode(d.group);
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d) {
    return colorNode(d.group);
  })

 // Append images
 var images = NodeCircleEnter.append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href",  function(d) {console.log(d); return d.image;})
    .attr("x", function(d) { return -25;})
    .attr("y", function(d) { return -25;})
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("width", 50);
```

this is my full code.

https://plnkr.co/edit/C2x7Zw5FkXHCUEpgWYWE?p=preview

Now, I cant move the nodes:

[image]

Comment: You need to look at your tick function, I'm running out right now, but you are updating the link position, text position, but neither the circles nor image position in the tick function - you do update `node`s cx/cy attributes, but it isn't a selection of circles.

Comment: thanks... NodeCircleEnter instead of "node" ? the circles position not changes...

Comment: @yavg no, you cannot just change the selection's name, you have to change the code for dealing with groups, which have no `cx` or `cy` attributes. Here is the fixed code: https://www.plnkr.co/edit/9uH13N3or3G9VTgQlMm9?p=preview

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you very much for your response, it is almost as I need it. the only problem is that being an image does not allow me to drag or move my nodes. it's as if the force diagram is not working. publish your answer to qualify it please.

Comment: I am able to drag the nodes in the updated plunkr, perhaps I am misunderstanding - do you want to "reheat" the simulation on drag?

Comment: @AndrewReid thanks for answering, you are very kind. I can drag and zoom in my svg. Right?. I can also drag and move each node as a normal force layout would. this could be done before the update of this plnkr. I can only drag globally but I have no interaction on each node after the problem with the images was fixed.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado do you know what is my problem?

Comment: @yavg No, I'm not following it. Didn't my JSFiddle fix the issue?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes it solved it, but it caused another problem. I can no longer move the nodes (if I can zoom in on the global g and drag, but I can not interact with the nodes, it's as if there is no force system)

Comment: @yavg I see. So, if it caused **another** problem you have to ask **another** question, with all relevant details (for instance, in my fiddle I can mode the nodes, so you have to reproduce the problem).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I tried to be as clear as possible (I updated the questión with a .gif).. I do not know why I can not move my nodes as in the example I show you in the gif. it seems that the image does not leave the cursor interaction with the nodes.

Comment: publish your answer to qualify, and additionally I published another question, if you are interested in answering, I have not been able to solve it. thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081942/i-can-not-move-my-nodes-the-force-diagram-does-not-apply-in-3-js