# I can not move my nodes, the force diagram does not apply in 3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In a previous question a user helped me with a problem that consisted in not knowing how to put images where the circles are. this time my problem is that I can not drag the nodes. This gif illustrates my problem (first I show how the nodes should move normally, then I illustrate my problem.).

[image]

Why does this happen?

```
var link = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("stroke", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    return colorLink(d.group);
  })
  .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");

var node = g.selectAll("g.node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  //.filter(function(d){ return d.type=="circle"; })
var NodeCircleEnter= node.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class","node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })

  NodeCircleEnter
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return colorNode(d.group);
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d) {
    return colorNode(d.group);
  })

// Append images
var images = NodeCircleEnter.append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href",  function(d) {console.log(d); return d.image;})
    .attr("x", function(d) { return -25;})
    .attr("y", function(d) { return -25;})
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("width", 50);
```

This is my full code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/9uH13N3or3G9VTgQlMm9?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handlers need to be applied to the elements themselves rather than the canvas as a whole.

In this code (only existing in your Plunker project, but not in your question):

```js
var drag_handler = d3.drag()
  .on("start", drag_start)
  .on("drag", drag_drag)
  .on("end", drag_end);

drag_handler(node);
```

Your variable `node` is the drawing. You actually want a collection of elements to affect which you get from functions like `.enter()`. Your variable `NodeCircleEnter` contains that collection so the particular line should be:

```js
drag_handler(NodeCircleEnter);
```

This still leaves an issue where dragging on the labels themselves doesn't work. This is because the labels aren't children of the elements you set the handlers on.

Comment: it seems that it works! .. how can I do so that the dragging of the nodes is not confused with those of the global g element that zooms...

Comment: @yavg I'm not sure what you mean. From what I can tell, that change is enough to make it work for both dragging elements and the pan/zoom effect independantly.

Comment: I understand my problem, when I try to drag the nodes with the cursor over the text, the nodes do not move, the scenario moves. I do not know if I make myself understood. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: @yavg As I explained in my answer, this is due to the labels not being children of the nodes. An obvious solution is to arrange for the labels to be children of the node elements.

Comment: One last question please, what is the property to have the links curved? my code is something different from this one, that's why I do not know. http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/be2abfb3155a38be4de4

Comment: @yavg They generate those paths manually by creating a path element and computing an arc for it. The relevant code starts at `path.attr("d", function(d) {`.